# Self-hosted framework for translation like google translate api?

Tags: frameworks, translation

I am currently developing an enterprise software. The client stated the need to translate certain texts that we gather from different sources into their home language, or at least into English. Due to GDPR concerns we cannot use external APIs like Google Translate API or DeepL. We need to have either a self-hosted solution or even better, just a python framework that contains translation logic for different languages internally.

Do you know of any such framework?

Answer (score 0):

[LibreTranslate](https://libretranslate.com/) seems to be a good option that we will be trying out.